# How can i use fromEvent (Angular rxjs) with multiple Elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular Application with multiple Buttons which have specific IDs. each of them has a click function and I want to track if a user clicked the Button without changing anything in each of the Methods.

example code:

```
  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  
  

    @ViewChild('BUTTON_EDIT', {read: ElementRef}) BUTTON_EDIT;
      @ViewChild('BUTTON_ADD', {read: ElementRef}) BUTTON_ADD;
      ele: Element;
      
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        let clickStream;
    
        //check which element was pressed and get the id
        //how can i check it?

        clickStream = fromEvent(this.ele, 'clicked');
        var id = this.ele.id;
    
        clickStream.subscribe(event => {
          //send info
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: This code is not working ? where is the problem ? and what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: this is just an example, i want to know if and how it is possible to do that

Comment: Unrelated to question, but AFAIK the event must be `click`: `fromEvent(this.ele, 'click')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular allows you to bind more than one method to a click event. This means you can bind a common "click" method that takes in the element's ID and does not modify the event handler method that is specific to that button as follows:

```html
<button id="add-btn" #addBtn (click)="click(addBtn.id); add()">
  Add
</button>

<button id="edit-btn" #editBtn (click)="click(editBtn.id); edit()">
  Edit
</button>
```

The `click` method does the tracking of all button clicks while the `add` and `edit` method are the event handlers that are specific to each button.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y9uain?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 4):

In order to listen to multiple events you can use [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge), which

> Turn multiple observables into a single observable

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    merge(
        fromEvent(this.BUTTON_EDIT.nativeElement, 'click'),
        fromEvent(this.BUTTON_ADD.nativeElement, 'click'),
    ).subscribe((event: Event)=> {
      console.log(event.target.id);
    });
  }
```

There is also an article - [Create Observable from Event using FromEvent in Angular](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/create-observable-from-event-using-fromevent-in-angular/) which explains details.

**Events in Web APIs**

For emitted [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) there is [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, from where you can get element's id, there is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a907jf5g/

**Angular approach to listen to click event**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
    <button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent {
  add() {
    // add clicked
  }

  edit() {
    // edit clicked
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i get the id of the clicked element?

Comment: Why do you need ids?

Comment: i want to track if the button was clicked so i need the id to know which button

Comment: updated my answer, although I would say in Angular, you don't need to use ids much. Its not like jQuery where you need to operate with DOM elements directly.